# How to get result out from xpath using php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, xpath

Im trying to get the text out xpath/html using php..but not successful any idea.

Example:
https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=google.com

My xpath (This is correct i already double check)
`//*[@id="bodyContent"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/b`

I want to get a result to appear here `<div> result </div>` using php

Below is my code:

```
<?php
public function getNortonSafe($domain)
{
  try
  {
    $callback_url = "https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=google.com"; //. $domain;

    $curl_response = $this->curl->get($callback_url);

    if ($curl_response->headers['Status-Code'] == "200") {

      libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
      $this->dom_doc->loadHTML($curl_response);
      libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

      $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom_doc);
      $tmp = $xpath->query('//*[@id="bodyContent"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/b')->item(0)->textContent);

      $tmp = explode(' ', trim($tmp));
      $norton_site_test = str_replace(",", "", $tmp[0]);

    } else {
      $norton_site_test = "0";
    }

    $response = array(
      'status' => 'success',
      'data' => array(
        'norton_site_test' => filter_var($norton_site_test, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
      )
    );

  }
  catch (Exception $e)
  {
    $response = array(
      'status' => 'error',
      'msg' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  return $response;
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<p id="norton_site_test">  result-text-here </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Your XPath query is very complex, are you sure that it can't be simplified? Such a deep nesting is very fragile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing the `$xpath->query('some xpath here')->text(0)` line an error occurs: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::text()`. Please check your PHP [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings.

[DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) method returns `DOMNodeList` object that has only `item` method (see [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php)).
You need to call:

`$xpath->query('some xpath here')->item(0)->textContent`

to get the text content of the first node from the received DOMNodeList object.

Comment: I TRY BUT still not working - i think i have a problem here ` 'norton_site_test' => filter_var($norton_site_test)` How to filter the `text`? thanks in advance

Comment: Shall i used `filter_var($norton_site_test,textContent)`

Comment: It will be enough to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Just an Update regarding this code, and thank you to @camelsWrite - its working Now! with this clean code and tested:

```
    

    public function getNortonSafe($domain)
    {
        try
        {
            $callback_url = "https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url= . $domain; //e.g $url: "https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=google.com

            $curl_response = $this->curl->get($callback_url);

            if ($curl_response->headers['Status-Code'] == "200") {

                libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
                $this->dom_doc->loadHTML($curl_response);
                libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);

                $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom_doc);
                $tmp = $xpath->query('//*[@id="bodyContent"]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/b')->item(0)->textContent);

                $tmp = explode(' ', trim($tmp));
                $norton_site_test = str_replace(",", "", $tmp[0]);

            } else {
                $norton_site_test = "0";
            }

            $response = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => array(
                    'norton_site_test' => filter_var($norton_site_test)
                )
            );

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'msg' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        return $response;
    } ?>
```